Extremely strange behavior of kubectl exec for deployment/<name> vs <pod-name>
I am getting results that are really surprising me, and the docs aren't helping me understand.
I have a deployment configured via kustomize.
There is currently 1 pod in the deployment.
I am getting different results for the following 2 commands, which I wouldn't expect.
kubectl exec deployment/name -- sha256sum <file>

vs
kubectl exec <podname> -- sha256sum <file>

I checked the ReplicaSets for the deployment. There are multiple ReplicaSets, but there is only one with a non-zero number of pods.
I suspect that kubernetes is somehow finding a non-gced container that in some sense still belongs to the deployment. This is incredibly non-intuitive, as that container doesn't show up anywhere that I can see. I only can reason about its existence because of this strange action at a distance.
Happy to share more details if you think they'll be relevant, but I seem to have distilled it down to its essence.

It turned out that I had flubbed the selector matchLabels
This led to 4 deployments, all of which thought they had 4 pods in them.
The name prefixing, deployment1-<random> was confusing me, because it wasn't really accurate. All 4 pods belonged to all 4 deployments.
This seems like it ought to be an exceptional case, and perhaps a warning should be included in kubectl describe deployment <foo>.
Warning: This deployment spec matches pods created by deployment <blah>,
and deployment <blah> considers them to belong to the deployment <blah> as well.

I can imagine there are use cases for overlapping deployments, but I have to think they are exceptional and not the rule. Or even a deployment matching pods that aren't part of the Deployment->ReplicaSet->Pod Hierarchy of ownership.

kubectl - kubectl controls the Kubernetes cluster manager
kubectl exec - Execute a command in a container
The difference between two commands: If you use kubectl exec deployment/name kubernetes will select a pod associated with that deployment and kubernetes not sure about which pod is selected if there are multiple pods under deployment. If the old pod is still in the process of termination, it will also be selected.
Or if you use kubectl exec <podname\> it executes what exactly you specify, it directly interacts with a specific pod.
You mentioned you have multiple ReplicaSets but only one non-zero number of pods, it means that older ReplicaSets still exist from previous revision. To check ReplicaSets by using below comment kubectl get rs it will show current replicas deployed.
You are sure about no need for old Replicasets, To remove it by using the command kubectl delete rs <replicaset-name\>. You may test it, after deleting the ReplicaSet and then typing the command kubectl get pods into the terminal.
